# how to close a dao java

Tags: java, spring, performance, dao

In this piece of code, I need to close the dao. call the daoClose () method. but when can I call it and where? that was most effective.
I need to determine which connection is already hanging and then close it. how to catch this moment?

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7589862078860584987L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";
private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
private UserDao dao;

private long begin = System.nanoTime ();



public UserController() {
    super();
    dao = new UserDao();
} 



private void delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     dao.deleteUser(userId);
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}

private void edit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
     request.setAttribute("user", user);
}

private void listUsers(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}


private void common (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        delete(request, response);
        forward = LIST_USER;
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        edit(request, response);
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
        forward = LIST_USER;
       listUsers(request, response);
    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    try {
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

In this piece of code, I need to close the dao. call the daoClose () method. but when can I call it and where? that was most effective.
I need to determine which connection is already hanging and then close it. how to catch this moment?

```
private void commonSec( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
    user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
    try {
        Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
        user.setDob(dob);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
    if(userid == null || userid.isEmpty())
    {
        dao.addUser(user);
    }
    else
    {
        user.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(userid));
        dao.updateUser(user);
    }

    RequestDispatcher views = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
    listUsers(request, response);
    try {
        views.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    common(request, response);
    System.out.println(delta);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    commonSec(request, response);
    System.out.println(delta);

 }

private void daoClose() {

    dao.closeCn();
    System.out.println("run");
}

private long end = System.nanoTime ();
private long delta = end - begin;




 }
```

Comment: as you have tagged spring, mention a brief about your dao layer. as part of the coding standard, close should be called automatically. you dont have to call it explicitly. using spring jpa, it automatically does it for you.Or try reading about AutoCloseable interface at leasst.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the dao gets closed regardless of success/failure you can use the `finally` block.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

example

```
try {
    // use your dao
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
} finally {
    daoClose();
}
```

any code inside of the finally block is guaranteed to run, so you can ensure your dao gets closed at the end no matter if an error occured or not

Comment: see. i have a dao connection. I turn to the servlet and do something, then I turn again to the servlet, a new connection is already happening, there is a big load, if each time the connection is closed, then this is wasteful in resources, another method is needed. as it should be calculated when the connection is no longer used and close it. how to do it?

Comment: How to catch the moment when the connection is not used?

Comment: you advise transactions how to apply them here?

Comment: how can I use HttpSessionListener ?

Comment: I suggest you follow some standard hello world MVC controller, dao, service type tutorial, follow that pattern, then you won't need to deal with any resources like this.

Comment: задача в точности. I applied so

Comment: Открытый класс UserController расширяет HttpServlet реализует HttpSessionListener {некоторый код ...  @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
  daoClose(); 
  System.out.println("sessionDestroyed");
 }

Comment: Well, how will you get access to the dao object in the sessionDestroyed method, which should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `try(UserDao dao = new UserDao())`, do not have this as a member of the class it will not be thread safe. I suggest you read a little more about transactions, also follow the regular way things are done when you start learning.

Comment: see. i have a dao connection. I turn to the servlet and do something, then I turn again to the servlet, a new connection is already happening, there is a big load, if each time the connection is closed, then this is wasteful in resources, another method is needed. as it should be calculated when the connection is no longer used and close it. how to do it?

Comment: How to catch the moment when the connection is not used?

Comment: how can I use HttpSessionListener ?